# browser rendering profiling tools

Tags: javascript, browser, profiler

What are some free (and not free) browser profiling tools?

I know of a few:

- firebug profile / net panel
- YSlow
- google's version of yslow (forget the name)
- dynaTrace Ajax (free)

Am i missing anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE8 has a nice one.

Answer (score 0):

- Opera Dragonfly
- WebKit Inspector

Comment: Opera Dragonfly does not have a profiler, as of version 1.1 (Sep 2011).